# Get hour and minute to display on calendar using javascript language in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have difficulties, i'm not familiar with javascript. I need to add the time (in hour and minute ) from the calendar selection. Until now i'm not able to add it. i have try to play and test but not working. Can anyone help me to give any hint which part i need to focus on the script. Refer to attachment.

```html
<script language="javascript">

var thisPage = "calendarSearch.html";
var formName = "formPicker";
var field_name = "begin_date";

monthsNames = Array( "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" );

var tempString = location.search.substring( 1 );
if ( tempString.indexOf( "&" ) != -1 ) {
 var temp1  = tempString.split( "&" );
 var strField = temp1[ 0 ];
 var temp2  = temp1[ 1 ];
 var strData  = temp2.split( "," );
} else {
 var strField = tempString;
 var strData  = tempString.split( "," );
}

var strMonth = parseInt( strData[ 0 ], 10 );
var strYear  = parseInt( strData[ 1 ], 10 );

var dateObject = new Date();
var thisMonth = dateObject.getMonth();
var thisYear = dateObject.getFullYear();
var curMonth = dateObject.getMonth();
var curDay  = dateObject.getDate();
var curYear  = dateObject.getFullYear();

if (( strMonth > 0 ) || ( strYear > 0 )) {
 curMonth = strMonth;
 curYear  = strYear;
}

var today  = new Date( curYear, curMonth, 1 );
var today  = today.getDay();


function daysPerMonth( month, year ) {
 days = 31;
 if (( month == 4 )||( month == 6 )||( month == 9 )||( month == 11 )) {
  days = 30;
 } else if ( month == 2 ) {
  if (((( year % 100 ) == 0 ) && (( year % 400 ) == 0 )) || ((( year % 100 )!=0 ) && (( year % 4 ) == 0 ))) {
   days = 29;
  } else {
   days = 28;
  }
 }
 return days;
}


function monthBack( month, year ) {
 if ( month == 0 ) {
  location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&" + 11 + "," + ( year - 1 );
 } else {
  location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&"  + ( month - 1 ) + "," + year;
 }
}

function monthForward( month, year ) {
 if ( month == 11 ) {
  location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&" + "0" + "," + ( year + 1 );
 } else {
  location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&" + ( month + 1 ) + "," + year;
 }
}

function yearBack( month, year ) {
 location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&" + ( month ) + "," + ( year - 1 );
}

function yearForward( month, year ) {
 location.href = thisPage + "?" + strField + "&" + ( month ) + "," + ( year + 1 );
}


function getYear( year ) {
 retval = new String( year );
 retval = retval.slice( 0, 4 );
 return retval;
}

function getMonth( month ) {
 month++;
 retval = new String( month );
 if ( retval < 10 ) {
  retval = "0" + retval;
 }
 return retval;
}

function getDay( day ) {
 retval = new String( day );
 if ( retval < 10 ) {
  retval = "0" + retval;
 }
 return retval;
}

function createCSS() {
 var cssStyle = "";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "<style type=text/css>";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "A:link { COLOR:#101010;TEXT-DECORATION:none; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "A:visited { COLOR:#101010;TEXT-DECORATION:none; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "A:active { COLOR:#101010;TEXT-DECORATION:none; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "A:hover { COLOR: #101010;TEXT-DECORATION:none; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + ".Numeric { FONT-FAMILY:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica;FONT-SIZE:10px;LINE-HEIGHT:16px; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + ".DaysLabel { FONT-FAMILY:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica;FONT-SIZE:11px;LINE-HEIGHT:16px;COLOR:#FF0000; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + ".TextLabel { FONT-FAMILY:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica;FONT-SIZE:12px;LINE-HEIGHT:16px; }";
 cssStyle = cssStyle + "</style>\r\n";
 return cssStyle;
}

function createDaysTable() {
 var daysTable = "";
 daysTable = daysTable + "<table width=80% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  <td align=center>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "   <table width=100% cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=left><span class=TextLabel><a href='javascript:monthBack(" + curMonth + "," + curYear + ")'><<</a>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=center><span class=TextLabel><b>" + monthsNames[ curMonth + 1 ] + "</b>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=TextLabel><a href='javascript:monthForward(" + curMonth + "," + curYear + ")'>>></a>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "   </table>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  <td align=center>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "   <table width=100% cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>S&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>M&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>T&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>W&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>T&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>F&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=DaysLabel>S&nbsp;</td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    <tr>\r\n";

 var dayCounter = 1;

 for ( x=0; x<today; x++ ) {
  daysTable = daysTable + "     <td></td>\r\n";
 }

 for ( x=today; x<7; x++ ) {
  var selected = "";
  //var strDate = getDay( dayCounter ) + "/" + getMonth( curMonth ) + "/" + getYear( curYear );
  var strDate = getYear( curYear ) + "/" + getMonth( curMonth ) + "/" + getDay( dayCounter );

  if (( dayCounter == curDay ) && ( curMonth == thisMonth ) && ( thisYear == curYear )) {
   selected = "<b>";
  }

  daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align='center'><font face=Verdana size=1><a href='#' onclick='window.opener.document." + formName + "." + strField + ".value=\"" + strDate + "\"; self.close();'>" + selected + "" + dayCounter + "</a></b></td>\r\n";
  dayCounter = dayCounter + 1;
 }

 for ( y=1; y<6; y++ ) {
  daysTable = daysTable + "    </tr>\r\n";
  daysTable = daysTable + "    <tr>\r\n";

  for ( z=0; z<7; z++ ) {
   var selected = "";
   //var strDate = getDay( dayCounter ) + "/" + getMonth( curMonth ) + "/" + getYear( curYear );
   var strDate = getYear( curYear ) + "/" + getMonth( curMonth ) + "/" + getDay( dayCounter );

   if ( dayCounter >= daysPerMonth( curMonth + 1, curYear )) {
    var z=7;
    var y=5;
   }

   if (( dayCounter == curDay ) && ( curMonth == thisMonth ) && ( thisYear == curYear )) {
    selected = "<b>";
   }

   daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=center><span class=Numeric><a href=# onclick='window.opener.document." + formName + "." + strField + ".value=\"" + strDate + "\"; self.close();'>" + selected + "" + dayCounter + "</a></b></td>\r\n";
   dayCounter = dayCounter + 1;
  }
  daysTable = daysTable + "    </tr>\r\n";
 }
 daysTable = daysTable + "   </table>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  <td align=center>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "   <table width=100% cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 border=0>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    <tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=left><span class=TextLabel><a href='javascript:yearBack(" + curMonth + "," + curYear + ")'><<</a>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=center><span class=TextLabel><b>" + curYear + "</b>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     <td align=right><span class=TextLabel><a href='javascript:yearForward(" + curMonth + "," + curYear + ")'>>></a>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "     </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "    </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "   </table>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "  </td>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + " </tr>\r\n";
 daysTable = daysTable + "</table>\r\n";
 return daysTable;
}


var htmlBody = "";
htmlBody = htmlBody + "<html><head><title>DATE PICKER</title></head>\r\n";
htmlBody = htmlBody + "<body bgcolor=#FFFFFF>\r\n";
htmlBody = htmlBody + "<div align=center>\r\n";
htmlBody = htmlBody + createCSS();
htmlBody = htmlBody + createDaysTable();
document.write( htmlBody );
</script>
</head>
```

The calendar should have the hour and minute for the selection. Current only have month, day and year selection.

Comment: Please don't use tabs for indenting, use spaces. You can't use *document.write* after the page has loaded, it will remove the entire content of the page (header and body), including the script that called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see `getMonth()` in your code, so you can use `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` by analogy or find another calendar already having hours and minutes selectors.